# Error 1004 - Select method of range class failed

Tags: vba, excel

OK, I know that Select is pain in the a... and have been discussed here many times. But none of the solved questions here helped me.

I am running the following code from MS Access, it exports some data and I need that when the client opens an exported workbook, the active cell is set to the top left of page "Intro".

I recently have upgraded to Office 2013 and the code stopped working. This code worked on my previous version of Office 2007.

The error is: Error 1004 - Select method of range class failed.

Code:

```
Private Sub SelectFrontPage(wbk as Object)
  wbk.Activate  ' maybe this line is not necessary
  wbk.Sheets("Intro").Activate  ' Activate or Select?
  wbk.Sheets("Intro").Range("A1").Select  ' here the debugger stops :(
End Sub
```

Updates:

1. sheet "Intro" is visible and the "A1" is also visible, which I
   assume make it selectable
2. also tried Cells(1,1) but the result is
   the same
3. also tried Range("A1").Activate, the same result again
4. also tried (wbk as Excel.Workbook), the result is the same

How I open Excel?

```
Dim xls As Object
Set xls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xls.EnableEvents = False
xls.DisplayAlerts = False
dim wbk as Object
set wbk = xls.Workbooks.Open("mytemplate.xlsm")
' ... some data export here
SelectFrontPage wbk
wbk.Save
wbk.Close
```

Another UPDATE:
I am using several templates, one of them has English sheet names, other has sheet names in local language. The English one works as expected. There must be something else to cause the problem... But the problem is not obviously with the sheet name, because the line activating the sheet passes fine.

When I add line

```
xls.Visible = True
```

after I open the Excel application, everything works as expected. OMG, what kind of sorcery is this?

Comment: Try `.Activate` instead.

Comment: I tried, with the same result. 'Activate method of Range class failed'

Comment: What about `wbk.Sheets("Intro").Cells(1, 1).Activate`

Comment: How is any of this being associated as within the `Excel.Application` object that you are running it under within Access?

Comment: Yes, can we please see how you run Excel and open the workbook? Also, why Exit Sub and not End Sub?

Comment: Jeeped: I do not understand what you mean - I am running this from VBA macro in Access, it opens Excel workbook, saves data to it, then it saves it and closes.

Comment: Anyway, this code works fine for me, **if** I properly launch Excel with a workbook inside.

Comment: @ vacip: Yes, End Sub of course, it was a misprint. Corrected.

Comment: @ vacip: When I run this code inside Excel it works fine. But when I run it from Access, it fails.

Comment: @V.K. what we are trying to say is: please paste the code that creates the Excel file and calls the SelectFrontPage subroutine. There seems to be no problem with the code you have pasted, so we must look somewhere else.

Comment: Eeee, well, there is no such thing as a range in access, so you need to specify that you are trying to run it inside an Excel, not an Access database. See here: [Open Excel from Access VBA](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=17905)

Comment: @vacip: I believe that because I am using late OLE binding, I do not need the reference to Excel. Nevertheless I have it set and it does not work.

Comment: Why do need to set active cell to the top left of page "Intro"? What this line of code changes?  Have you tried to use `Activate` instead of `Select` method?

Comment: @MaciejLos: Please read the whole question including the recent updates. I also explained why I need it at the beginning of the question.

Comment: @V.K., i had already read your question carefully. I have no idea why it's so important, what it changes?

Comment: @MaciejLos: OK, I will try to explain better. I have a template to which some data should be exported from Access. This template is changed time to time. It has some "Intro" sheet. After the data is exported to the template I want to activate the top left cell of the "Intro" sheet so that it is the first thing that the user can see when he opens the exported file. (as it might happen that someone who edited the template forgot to set the active cell to top left of "Intro" sheet...) Does this make sense?

Comment: Btw. I really do not understand why on Stack Overflow each question is followed by contra-question "Why do you need it?" Asking this will not help me solve the problem.

Comment: As I already mentioned in the update, when I visualize my export using `xls.Visible = true` the Range etc. miraculously works again... When the Excel is in the background, i.e. `xls.Visible = false` the Range etc. fails. Is this a Microsoft's bug?

Comment: Yes, this is a bug. That's why many developers says that using `Select` method is wrong approach.  As to the MS Excel top-left active cell. It does not matter what cell is currently active.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you need to declare Excel, you are passing wbk as an object, I try to pass as a workbook.

```
> Sub whatever(wb as Excel.Workbook)
>         Dim  ws As Worksheet
>         
>         Set ws = wb.Sheets("Intro")    
>         ws.Activate
>         ws.Cells(1, 1).Select
>     End Sub
```

Edit:
step 1:
You can go the workbook that is in question, select intro sheet choose cell A1 name the range to IntroHome.

to name a range push ctl+f3; name manager will appear; click on new; type the name in.

step 2
try this code

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Intro")
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = [IntroHome]
ws.Activate
rng.Select
```

Comment: did you also change "Range("A1")" to Cells(1,1)?

Comment: yes, please see the updates of my question to see what I already tried... there must be some completely different source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Select` method is wrong approach. It was mentioned several times on this and other programming forums.

If you want to make `A1` cell as a top-left corner of window, i'd suggest to use [Application.GoTo method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839232.aspx):

```
xls.Goto Reference:=wbk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1"), _ 
 scroll:=True
```

Note: I'm using `Worksheets(1)` instead of `Sheets(1)`, because `Sheets` collection can refer to `Charts` also. Please, read the documentation.

I tested above line of code in MS Word:

```
Sub DoWhatever()

Dim xls As Object, wbk As Object

Set xls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wbk = xls.Workbooks.Add()

xls.GoTo Reference:=wbk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1"), Scroll:=True
wbk.SaveAs "D:\aaa.xlsx"
wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
xls.Quit

Set wbk = Nothing
Set xls = Nothing
End Sub
```

Code has been executed without errors.

BTW: Don't know why it's still so important to make `A1` cell as a top-left corner of the MS Excel window. ;)

Comment: I am going to try GoTo but otherwise your code is basically the same as mine. It does not explain at all why my call of Select fails.

Comment: @V.K. did you have any luck using `Application.GoTo` instead of `Select/Activate` method?

Answer (score 0):

This is an Office 2013 change/bug.  You can't .Select or .Activate unless visible.  I'm afraid I don't have a workaround to suggest yet, as I only came across the issue after an upgrade to Office 2013.

Whether `Select` is appropriate depends on expected use-case. Often it is not. In this case, it may be that V.K.'s users expect a specific cell to be active when they open the workbook, perhaps so they can start data entry immediately, etc. Excel saves the currently active cell when you save the workbook, which persists when you open that workbook, obviously.